# Как сравнить два файла на идентичность?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

Есть два Git репозитория одного проекта, в одной из них стёрта история коммитов.

Как сравнить файлы в них и найти отличия?

Comment: в каком смысле "история коммитов стерта"? если в репозитории нет истории - в нем нет и самих коммитов.

Comment: @eg0r Непонятен вопрос. Разверните проблему более детально.

Comment: репозиторий (git) — это, собственно, и есть набор коммитов. если коммитов нет, то это *не* репозиторий, и сравнивать просто не с чем.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin как сравнить файлы на идентичность? быть может не с помощью самого `git`?

Comment: @MatthewHaig, например, подсчитать хэш-суммы файлов, и сравнить их. и при чём тут git вообще?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну это и ежу понятно, как сравнить текст внутри файлов?

Comment: @MatthewHaig, программой diff, например.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо, будем копать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Без коммитов ваш репозиторий - просто папка с файлами.

И есть множество средств для сравнения папок.
Консольные: comp (win) и diff (nix).
И визуальные: виндовый [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) и под мак [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/).
Последним периодически успешно пользуюсь.

Comment: для знающих толк месье есть `vimdiff` или `vim -d`

Comment: Эээ @Vetal4eg ты меня слышишь? За winMerge спасибо, классная штука. То что нужно.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin ʕ ᵔᴥᵔ ʔ